# Add calendar to meeting workspace (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a meeting workspace under an existing site, but there are less list types you can create for it. Since it is a 'meeting workspace' I am surprised that 'Calendar' is not under the list of types I can add. How can I add the option back (and any additional ones, e.g. 'custom list')?

Comment: did you know that this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ exists?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's not the way you are supposed to be using it.
The way to go is:

- create the calendar at root level
- for each meeting in the calendar you create a workspace to manage
  your resources for that meeting.

This way, you have only one calendar with all the events, and each meeting has its own workspace. You also avoid schedule conflict